# error C2062 : type int unexpected

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am new to c++ and SWIG

I am creating a python module using SWIG in windows environment.

After creating wrapper class (example_wrap.cxx). Started building using (python setup.py build_ext --inplace) for creating python module.

But I am getting ***example_wrap.cxx(3090) : error C2062: type 'int' unexpected***

GradedComplex.h:

```
class GradedComplex
{
public:
  typedef std::complex<double> dcomplex;
  typedef Item<dcomplex> item_type;
  typedef ItemComparator<dcomplex> comparator;
  typedef std::set<item_type, comparator> grade_type;

private:
  int n_;
  std::vector<grade_type *> grade_;
  std::vector<double> thre_;

public:
  GradedComplex(int n, double *thre);
  ~GradedComplex();

  void push(item_type item);
  void avg(double *buf);
};

#endif
```

GradedComplex.cc

```
GradedComplex::GradedComplex(int n, double *thre)
{
  n_ = n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_; ++i)
  {
    thre_.push_back(thre[i]);
    grade_.push_back(new grade_type());
  }
}
```

Then I build it for generating python module using SWIG.

Swig interface file (example.i)
    GradedComplex(int n, double *thre);

I am not much expert in SWIG interface file

The wrapper class generated has large volume of code so i am pasting few.

code : example_wrap.cxx

```
3083: #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
3084: #include "Item.h"
3085: #include "GradedComplex.h"
3086: typedef std::complex<double> dcomplex;
3087: typedef Item<dcomplex> item_type;
3088: typedef ItemComparator<dcomplex> comparator;
3089: typedef std::set<item_type, comparator> grade_type;   
3090: GradedComplex(int n, double *thre);
3091: void push(item_type item);
3092: void avg(double *buf);
3093: #include <string>
3094: #include <complex> 
3095: #include <iostream>
3096: #if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03020000
3097: # define SWIGPY_SLICE_ARG(obj) ((PyObject*) (obj))
3098: #else
3099: # define SWIGPY_SLICE_ARG(obj) ((PySliceObject*) (obj))
3100: #endif
```

The GradedComplex constructor:

```
GradedComplex::GradedComplex(int n, double *thre)
{
  n_ = n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_; ++i)
  {
    thre_.push_back(thre[i]);
    grade_.push_back(new grade_type());
  }
}
```

Please suggest a to rectify this error

Comment: @KirillKobelev That was a mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience . I have corrected it.

Comment: GradedComplex(int n, double *thre); doesn't have a return type.

Comment: Its a constructor added more code for clarification

Comment: @svs_swig: What is "its a constructor" supposed to mean? You have `GradedComplex(int n, double *thre)` sitting in the middle of the code, not inside any class. No, it is not a constructor. It is a function `GradedComplex` without a return type. This is illegal in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently declared class `GradedComplex` somewhere in some header file (`GradedComplex.h`?)

Later you attempted to use this name in this line

```
GradedComplex(int n, double *thre);
```

To a human reader this line would probably look like an attempt to declare an independent function `GradedComplex`. Technically, it is legal to have a function with the same name as an existing class. However, since you specified no return type for this function, the compiler does not see this as a function declaration. The compiler thinks you are trying to declare an object of type `GradedComplex` with redundant parentheses around the declarator, as in

```
GradedComplex (a);
```

For this reason, the appearance of that `int` confuses it and leads to an error report about an unexpected `int` in line 3090.

What were you trying to do? If you were trying to define a constructor for `GradedComplex`, then you already know how to do it (you posted a correct definition yourself). What is the purpose of line 3090? Why did you write that line?

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a function with no return type in c++. You should set a return type for the function `GradedComplex`. Constructors can not be declared like that.